# How do I subtract paths in elisp?

Tags: elisp

I've got two paths, one a subset of the other `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/bar/baz/gig`. The path I'd like to extract is `baz/gig`, the relative path of the file from the dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `file-relative-name`:

```
(file-relative-name "/foo/bar/baz/gig" "/foo/bar/")    ;   => "baz/gig"
```

Documented in the Elisp manual under "Relative File Names".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`f`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) third-party file manipulation library. [`f-relative`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-relative-path-optional-dir) is what you need.

```
(f-relative "/a/b/c/d/e/file.txt" "/a/b/") ; "c/d/e/file.txt"
(f-relative "/a/b/c/d/e/file.txt" "/a/b") ; "c/d/e/file.txt"
```